# CURL Progress Bar: How to pipe and extract numbers only using grep?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, curl, grep

This is what I have so far:

```
[my1@graf home]$ curl -# -o f1.flv 'http://osr.com/f1.flv' |  grep -o '*[0-9]*'
####################################################################### 100.0%
```

I wish to use grep and only extract the percentage from that progress bar that CURL outputs.

I think my regex is not correct and I am also not sure if this grep will take effect of the the percentage being continuously updated?

What I am trying to do is basically get CURL only to give me the percentage number as the output and nothing else.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the progress info like that through grep; it doesn't make sense.

`curl` writes the progress bar to stderr, so you have to redirect to stdout before you can grep it:

`$ curl -# -o f1.flv 'http://osr.com/f1.flv' 2>&1 | grep 1 | less` results in:

```
^M                                                                           0.0
%^M######################################################################## 100.
0%^M######################################################################## 100
.0%^M######################################################################## 10
0.0%
```

Are you expecting a continual stream of numbers that you are redirecting somewhere else?  Or do you expect to grab the numbers at a single point?

If it's the former, this sort of half-assedly works on a small file:

```
$ curl -# -o f1.flv 'http://osr.com/f1.flv' 2>&1 | sed  's/#//g' -
 100.0%                                                                    0.0%
```

But it's useless on a large file.  The output doesn't print until the download is finished, probably because curl seems to be sending ^H's to the terminal.  There might be a better way to `sed` it, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

```
$ curl -# -o l.tbz 'ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/2009/06/2009-06-02-05-mozilla-1.9.1/firefox-3.5pre.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2' 2>&1 | sed 's/#//g' -
 100.0%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Ah I see, redirect output so I can actually see it. I was hoping just to extract the numbers as they appear like you said (the former). I tried the above but I only get output when it reaches 100% - maybe I need a larger file to actually see the progress change?

Comment: Curl's output is meant to be read by humans, not by computers -- that's why the format sucks when taken in by grep.  You might have better luck using `wget --progress=dot` and counting the dots, but then it's not a percentage either.  Or maybe you would be able to just count the #'s in curl's output.  At least you'd get accuracy to 5-10%, or however many #'s fit in a terminal, right?

Comment: You are right, Probably better luck counting the hashes. I can't use wget since this is blocked by my host for some reason. A previous question I asked had the consensus that CURL is the next best choice if you can't use wget. Should of added which of the other options has an easy way of parsing the progress too!!

Answer (score 5):

With curl 7.36.0 (should also work for other versions) you can extract the percentage in the following way:

```
curl ... 2>&1 -# | stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n' | grep -o '[0-9]*\.[0-9]'
```

Here `...` stands for options/filenames. This outputs a sequence of percentage numbers.

Curl uses carriage returns `\r` in its output, so you need `tr` to transform them first into `\n` because `grep` is line oriented. You also need to modify output buffer settings with `stdbuf` to get the percentage numbers immediately after curl outputs them.

Comment: In my case, I also needed a `stdbuf -oL` before `grep`. Neat answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
curl source -o dest -# 2> tmp&

grep -o ".....%" tmp | tail -n1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .* not * in your regex.

```
grep -o '.*[0-9].*'
```

That will catch all text though, so maybe try:

```
grep -p '[0-9]+'
```

Comment: Do I need to further pipe this into echo to actually see the results of the grep?