# How to show a dialog/whiptail gauge for curl?

Tags: linux, shell, dialog, whiptail

I want to display a progress bar for `curl` using a `dialog`/`whiptail` `--gauge` box like:

```
curl -#OL https://website/myfile 2>&1 | \
??? stdbuf -o0 awk '???' ? | \
| whiptail --gauge "Downloading the file..." 6 64 0
```

I've found a solution for `wget` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784101/how-to-show-dialog-gauge-for-wget), that is very nice but i'm still searching a solution for `curl`. I've tried also to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132456/curl-progress-bar-how-to-pipe-and-extract-numbers-only-using-grep), no success.

Does anybody knows how to do a `dialog`/`whiptail` `--gauge` progress bar for `curl`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be more specific and provide the code snippet then we will able to help. Thanks!